Running Job After First Job Successfully Finishes
I'm currently setting up a pipeline that gets triggered by a pull request. Once the pipeline starts, tests are run. After the tests successfully run, I have a script that I want to approve the PR. When I attempt to set this pipeline using the fly command, I get the following error:

invalid jobs: jobs.pr_approver.plan.do[0].get(pr_approver).passed: job 'ci_concourse_test_pr' does not interact with resource 'pr_approver'

How can I restructure this to get the desired outcome, which is to have the pr_approver job run after the ci_concourse_test_pr successfully runs?
Here's my pipeline
---

resource_types:
  - name: pull-request
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: teliaoss/github-pr-resource

resources:
  - name: ci_concourse_test
    type: pull-request
    check_every: 168h
    webhook_token: {SECRET}
    source:
      repository: {GITHUB_REPO}
      access_token: {SECRET}
      v3_endpoint: https://api.github.com/
      v4_endpoint: https://api.github.com/graphql

  - name: ci_concourse_test_main
    type: git
    source:
      branch: main
      uri: {GITHUB_REPO}
      private_key: {SECRET}

  - name: pr_approver
    type: git
    source:
      branch: main
      uri: {GITHUB_REPO}
      private_key: {SECRET}


jobs:
  - name: ci_concourse_test_pr
    plan:
      - get: ci_concourse_test
        trigger: true
      - put: ci_concourse_test
        params:
          path: ci_concourse_test
          status: pending
      - task: sample-test
        config:
          platform: linux
          image_resource:
            type: docker-image
            source:
              repository: {DOCKER_REPO}
              tag: latest
          inputs:
            - name: ci_concourse_test
          run:
            path: python3
            args: [ "ci_concourse_test/ci/test.py" ]
        on_success:
          put: ci_concourse_test
          params:
            path: ci_concourse_test
            status: success
         
          
          on_failure:
            put: ci_concourse_test
            params:
              path: ci_concourse_test
              status: failure

# Attempting to approve the PR
  - name: pr_approver
      plan:
        - get: pr_approver
        passed: [ci_concourse_test_pr]
        trigger: true
        - task: pr_approver
          config:
            platform: linux
            image_resource:
              type: docker-image
              source:
                repository: {GITHUB_REPO}
                tag: latest
            inputs:
              - name: pr_approver
            run:
              path: python3
              args: [ "github_interface/test.py" ]



In this config you told to the second job to get input pr_approver from the first job with the parametrer passed otherwise the first job dosn't interract with the ressource pr_approver.
To solve this you have two solution:

Add the ressource pr_approver as input to the first job



- name: ci_concourse_test_pr
    plan:
      - get: ci_concourse_test
        trigger: true
      - put: ci_concourse_test
        params:
          path: ci_concourse_test
          status: pending
      - get: pr_approver
      - task: sample-test
      ....




Find another common ressource between job to trigger second one after that the first one is successfly finishe

